# MongoDB cluster network Resilience with 2 ethernet only

Tags: mongodb, failovercluster

I wonder if it is possible to configure a network resilience mongodb cluster using only 2 ethernet adapter card on each node.
I configured the cluster with 3 nic *emulating* the third nic using vip defined on the 1st adapter. It's just an exercise to test config and replica-set voting.

In case of network switch failure in the worst case I lost **2** routes at the same time.

Asking for a server board with dual port NICs is normal and cheap opposite to quad port which are not always available (i.e. blade servers)

Thanks in advance to everybody for any idea or suggestion.

```
                    +-------+               
      +-------------+ host1 +---------------+
      |        eth0 +-------+ eth1          |
      |                                     |
      |                                     |
      |port3                           port3|
+-----+----+                          +-----+----+
|          |port2       ISL      port2|          |
| switch A +--------------------------+ switch B |
|          |                          |          |
+-----+----+                          +-----++---+
      |port1                           port1|
      |             +-------+               |
      +-------------+ host2 +---------------+
               eth0 +-------+ eth1
```

PS: (I know that it could be possible if the underlying OS offers NIC teaming (linux eth bonding), my question is if MongoDB can do it  *on its own*!

Comment: Why would one want to have it? The UNIX philosophy of software is "Do one thing and do it good!" If you start something like network bonding inside an DBMS, why not add a kitchen sink, too? ;)

Comment: I prefer an architecture where cluster resource and data availability are decoupled from OS intrinsics; beyond this consideration Linux nic bonding is able to cover 100% of my requirements; for a cheap solution maybe it’s better to add third nic on mongo server than adopt L3 switches with 802.1Q and STP ( dd-wrt ??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my old question and two years later:

2 Box Mongodb cluster is unusual because of *majority* logic on replicaset.

3 or 5 or 7 boxes with 3 eth port on each node is enough and 3 network switches is enough without bonding.

Just enable STP on network switches for avoid loop